# How can I sum a pandas data frame by only custom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

I want to group the values by account and get summed rows but only where account is the same. I want a scalable version of it which can do this over 10,000 rows

What I have right now:

```
account  1      2
a       100     30
a       20      40
c       30      30
c       40      20
```

What I want:

```
account 1     2
a       120   70
b       70    50
```

Comment: `df.groupby('account').sum()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` + `reset_index`:

```
sums = df.groupby('account').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> sums
  account    1   2
0       a  120  70
1       c   70  50
```